# A D20 labelled {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,20} is rolled 8 times, is the probability of at least two consecutive 1s 25599203481/25600000000

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recursion

This `D20` has nineteen of its sides labelled as `{1}`, and the last one labelled as `{20}`.  If this die is rolled `8` times, there are `25,600,000,000` possible different outcomes.  Please confirm, prove or show that there are `25,599,203,481` out of all possible cases, which have at least two `{1}` rolled next to each other.

Two or more `{20}` do not satisfy this.  For example, the rolls `{1,20,1,20,20,20,1,20}` is a `false` instance, because there are no two consecutive rolls with `{1}` in this string.

The method that I used to get this answer was not brute forced, but I am wanting to compare my method with maybe a simpler method that may exist.

I am only an amateur mathematician, but also help people in doing the math of their board game designs, and while this math problem seems like a fringe question, I have constructed it as a fringe case of a project that I have been working on.

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to compare your method with some other method given that you never gave any details what your method was! If you give us the details on your method, then we can give a meaningful response.

Comment: Are all the faces of the die equally probable?

Comment: Of course.  That is what $D_{20}$ means.  And is clearly implied.  What else could the OP have possibly meant??

Comment: @bernard-massé yes, all sides are equal.  Or this could be considered a biased coin, whose heads are biased to 19/20, and tails are 1/20.

Comment: Do you know how to define a recursive solution when dealing with a fair coin?  For the common method, the recursion is one-step and two-state  (or three state, e.g. as a Markov chain) and the biased nature of it just changes a single parameter

Comment: I used linear recursion and convolution to get my answer @brian-moehring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to proceed. I will replace the outcomes $1$ and $20$ by $1$ and $0$. We consider the following Markov chain with states $0,1,2$:

```
     1        1
[0] ---> [1] ---> [2]
 A        |
 |        |
  \______/
```

which counts the consecutive ones.

- The state $0$ means "no two consecutive ones so far, last result is empty or a $0$".
- The state $1$ means "no two consecutive ones so far, last result is $1$".
- The state $2$ means "two consecutive ones were already obtained". This state is absorbant, once we land here, we never quit.

Let $p=19/20$ be the probability to "read" an one, and $q=1-p=1/20$ the opposite probability.
The transition matrix for this chain is
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
q & p & 0\\
q & 0 & p\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Then we can compute easily (with a computer of course) the value of $A^8$.

```
gp > p = 19/20; q = 1-p;
gp > A = [q, p, 0; q, 0, p; 0, 0, 1];
gp > A^8
%6 =
[10223/1280000000 592059/25600000000 25599203481/25600000000]
[31161/25600000000 173299/25600000000 1279989777/1280000000]
[0 0 1]
```

So the probability to get from $0$ to $2$ in eight steps is that entry `25599203481/25600000000`.

Comment: Markov Chains really do, do so much, so very powerful and obvious that I can apply these here.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would be better expressed the other way around: the probability that a roll does *not* have two consecutive ones is $796519/(20^8)$, or in other words the number of ways of not getting two consecutive ones is $796519$.

The recurrence relation is pretty straightforward. Rather than have all these duplicate '1's kicking around, I'm going to use a regular d20 and look at the number of ways of *not* rolling two consecutive non-20 results. This is most simply looked at in terms of two sequences: $a_n$, the number of sequences without two consecutive non-20s where the last result is a 20, and $b_n$, the number of such sequences where the last result isn't a 20. Then we see that $a_{n+1} = a_n+b_n$, because putting a 20 on the end of a valid sequence gives a valid sequence regardless of whether it previously ended in 20 or not. Likewise, $b_{n+1}=19a_n$, because we can't put any non-20 result on a sequence that didn't end in 20, but we can put nineteen different results on a sequence that did.

Putting these together, we have that $a_{n+1}=a_n+19a_{n-1}$, and the result that you want for a sequence of length $n$ is $a_n+b_n=a_{n+1}$. This is a fibonacci-style recurrence relation, and it can easily be solved with all of the usual techniques for solving linear recurrence relations.

Comment: I really need to look at the negative-cases more.  This is so obvious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cases where the rolls do **not** have consecutive $1s$ need to be $796519$, easily computable on a pocket calculator as

$1 + \binom8 1\cdot19 + \binom 7 2\cdot{19}^2 + \binom6 3\cdot{19}^3 +\binom5 4\cdot{19}^4 = 796519$

The term $\binom 7 2\cdot{19}^2$, for instance is where there are $two\; 1's \;and \;six\; 20's$, giving $7$ spaces for the $1's$ in the interstices of the $20's$ including the ends.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the notation to consider a coin with $P(H) = 19/20$ and $P(T) = 1/20$, and let $0 \leq n \leq 8$ be the number of $H$s in the sequence of $8$.  Clearly if $n = 0$ or $1$ there are no consecutive $H$s.  Likewise if $5 \leq n \leq 8$ you must have two successive $H$s.

Thus the only cases we must consider are $n = 2,3,4$.

For $n=2$, there are just $7$ cases:  $HHTTTTTT$, $THHTTTT$, etc.

For $n=4$, there are just two cases where there are *no* $TT$ sequences:  $HTHTHTHT$ and $THTHTHTH$.  Compute the total number with 4 Ts and 4 Hs, and then subtract $2$.

For $n=3$, place $HH$ in any of 6 paired slot, and for each consider the possible positions for the remaining $H$.  (Be careful to not overcount!)